# condition is not working in Birt

Tags: javascript, birt

i am trying to achieve this: 
If any of the data is missing on a specific line, I want you to make that line TWICE as tall and have underlines . can anyone suggest me how would i do that . my if condition is

```
if (row["Post_Converted"] || row["StatusDesc"] || row["RowVersionInitials"]) = null{
// add table border for that particular row 

}
```

please suggest me with some idea

Answer (score 0):

comparision is done with `==` and each value needs its own value to compare to. I suggest you start with learning the basics of JavaScript.

```
if (row["Post_Converted"] == null || row["StatusDesc"] == null || row["RowVersionInitials"] == null) {
    // add table border for that particular row 

}
```